# Map of two entity classes with separated cascading behavior for key / value

Tags: java, jpa-2.0

I've three entity classes `Key` , `Value` and `X` where `X` by now looks like

```
public class X {
  ...
  @ManyToMany
  Map<Key, Value> aMap;
  ...
}
```

My goal is to configure `aMap` that way, that `Value` will be deleted from db but
`Key` stays, when I remove a mapping from it.
Basically, `Key` should stay untuched from all db operations of `X`, but `Value` 
should just exist in coexistence with `X`.
Is this possible?

Comment: Simply overwrite the key with your null string